# Split separate lines to create filename

Tags: perl

I am very new to Perl and have a piece of code I am trying to modify. It opens a txt file and look for a serial number and renames that file with the serial number value. I am trying to also grab the part information and prepend that to the serial number.

The files looks something like this:

```
999511.RPT
C:\users\name\test
Program Name      : Automation123
Part Number       : A123987_2
Board #           : 1
Serial #          : 999511
Machine #         : AX-976
Operator #        : 98512
```

Now from that, I want to go through the file and pull the Part Number and the Serial # and rename the file.

So I would loop through the open file, grab those two values using a `split`, and the file would be renamed from `999511.RPT` to `A123987_2-999511.RPT` (I also need to add the `-` between those two values).

Right now we are doing a Line_Count since this RPT is always the same but I think there must be an easier way to search and extract these two values. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex to match the key, with grouping to extract the value:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my %extracted;
while (<>) {
    if (my ($key, $value) = /^(Serial #|Part Number)\s*:\s*(.*)/) {
        $extracted{$key} = $value;
    }
}

rename $ARGV,
    $extracted{'Part Number'} . '-' . $extracted{'Serial #'} . '.RPT'
    or die $!;
```

If you want to process several files at once, you can use [eof](http://p3rl.org/eof) to detect the end of each file:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my %extracted;
while (<>) {
    if (my ($key, $value) = /^(Serial #|Part Number)\s*:\s*(.*)/) {
        $extracted{$key} = $value;
    }
    if (eof) {
        rename $ARGV,
            $extracted{'Part Number'} . '-' . $extracted{'Serial #'} . '.RPT'
            or die $!;
        undef %extracted;
    }
}
```

Comment: You may as well just read the whole file into the hash. `my %extracted = map { chomp; split /\s*:\s*/ } <>`